# Magento 2.x default setup with custom extension

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have custom extension in my magento2.x, and i have start installation and its working but at some point installation is stop for an hour or may be more.

When i install with default setup before adding custom extension its working fine.

but when i install magento2.x with including custom extension then it not working.

Why we can not install with custom extension?

Answer (score 0):

Install clean magento first. Add extension with composer after.

Comment: Why we can not install with custom extension?